# Difference between one-hot-encoded and integer output in Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Consider the case of a multiclass classification problem with 12 classes (classes 0 to 11). These classes are **nominal** categorical variables (no ranking order).

I have trained two models (`M1` and `M2`), as follows:

`M1`: The output vector, `y_train`, is provided in one-hot-encoded format:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`M2`: The output vector, `y_train`, is provided as integer values.

```
array([ 6,  8,  1, ..., 11,  0,  4], dtype=int64)
```

I have trained these models with [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). Below you can see the code of the two models for the Random Forest (the codes for the MLP are exactly the same, just changing the Classifier type).

Code for `M1`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df['FLAG'].values

# One-hot-encode labels
label_bin = LabelBinarizer()
unique_classes = np.unique(y)
label_bin.fit_transform(unique_classes )

# Train-test split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
del x, y

# RF
# one-hot-output
y_train_one_hot = label_bin.transform(y_train)

classifier_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='entropy', min_samples_split=2,
                                       min_samples_leaf=1,
                                       random_state=42)

# Train
classifier_RF.fit(x_train, y_train_one_hot)
# Predict on test set
y_pred = classifier_RF.predict(x_test)
# Inverse predictions
y_pred_orig = label_bin.inverse_transform(y_pred)
# Classification report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_orig))
```

and this for `M2`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df['FLAG'].values

# Train-test split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
del x, y

# RF

classifier_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='entropy', min_samples_split=2,
                                       min_samples_leaf=1,
                                       random_state=42)

# Train
classifier_RF.fit(x_train, y_train)
# Predict on test set
y_pred = classifier_RF.predict(x_test)
# Classification report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Are these codes technically correct or am i missing something? I am asking this, because so far i have found that in the case of a multiclass problem, the `M1` approach (one-hot-encode output) is the correct/suitable one.  But, i am getting a higher `f1-score` in the `y_test` set, for the `M2` approach. While `M1` is `0.73`, the `M2` gives me `0.77`. This also happened when i use `MLPClassifier`. The `M1`for `MLPClassifier` is `0.73` while for `M2` is `0.76`.

**EDIT:** Here is the `M1` MLP:

```
classifier_MLP = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(2*x_train.shape[1], 2*y_train_one_hot.shape[1]),
                               max_iter=250,
                               random_state=42)
```

and here he `M2`:

```
classifier_MLP = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(2*x_train.shape[1], len(np.unique(y_train))),
                               max_iter=250,
                               random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `one-hot-encoding` and `integer-encoding` is based on the ordinal relationship between the classes. It means when you apply `one-hot-encoding` on classes, the distance between class 4 and 5 is equal to the distance of class 4 and 10.

So, both of your approach is totally correct and making the decision of which approach should be taken, is with the nature of your data, but you should note that for classification purpose between multi classes, in many cases, `one-hot-encoding` can give you the better result(because many ML algorithms are better to work with that such as `SVM`)

Comment: Could you elaborate more in the "wich approach should be taken, is with the nature of your data" part? I totally agree that the `one-hot-encoding` approach should be better, but not in my case for both Classifiers. There is something in my data that could cause this?